# splitting substrings and creating new columns for each in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am would like to split a space delimited string into 5 and create columns for each, but am finding it difficult to produce the desired output. 
Edit: using standard SQL dialect

sample data:

```
Row published_at                data_string          device id 
1   2016-10-26T22:53:03.209Z    70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 nan nan nan nan    2a0025000351353337353037
... 
1 of 570 rows
```

desired output:

```
Row published_at                battery temp1  humid1 temp2  humid2 temp3 humid3 device_id   
1   2016-11-03T16:24:09.833Z    70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 2a0025000351353337353037 
1 of 570 rows
```

attempted query 1.a:

```
WITH
  h2a0025_2 AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2016-10-26T22:53:03.209Z' AS published_at,
    '70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 nan nan nan nan' AS data_string,
    '2a0025000351353337353037' AS device_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2016-10-26T22:53:03.209Z',
    '70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 nan nan nan nan',
    '2a0025000351353337353037' )
SELECT
  published_at,
  parts[OFFSET(0)] AS Battery,
  parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Temp1,
  parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Humid1,
  parts[OFFSET(2)] AS Temp2,
  parts[OFFSET(3)] AS Humid2,
  parts[OFFSET(4)] AS Temp3,
  parts[OFFSET(5)] AS Humid3,
  device_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(data_string),
    SPLIT(data_string, ' ') AS parts
  FROM
    `h2a0025_2`);
```

result 1.a: 2 identical rows

```
  Row   published_at                battery temp1  humid1 temp2  humid2 temp3 humid3 device_id   
    1   2016-11-03T16:24:09.833Z    70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 2a0025000351353337353037 
    2   2016-11-03T16:24:09.833Z    70.77 3.38 61.65 7.98 73.20 3.29 63.55 2a0025000351353337353037
2 of 2 rows
```

attempt 2:

```
 SELECT
      published_at,
      parts[OFFSET(0)] AS Battery,
      parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Temp1,
      parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Humid1,
      parts[OFFSET(2)] AS Temp2,
      parts[OFFSET(3)] AS Humid2,
      parts[OFFSET(4)] AS Temp3,
      parts[OFFSET(5)] AS Humid3,
      device_id
    FROM (
      SELECT
        * EXCEPT(data_string),
        SPLIT(data_string, ' ') AS parts
      FROM
        `myproject.mydataset.h2a0025_2`);
```

Result: 
      Query Failed
      Error: Array index 3 is out of bounds (overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started. Instead of trying to get the right substring locations, use the `SPLIT` function and then pick out the offsets that you want in the resulting array.

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03T16:24:09.833Z' AS published_at,
    '80.91 22.15 45.35 14.41 64.54' AS data_string
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2016-11-04T18:34:08.143Z',
    '75.37 28.43 31.17 34.80 19.33'
)
SELECT
  published_at,
  parts[OFFSET(0)] AS Temp1,
  parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Humid1,
  parts[OFFSET(2)] AS Temp2,
  parts[OFFSET(3)] AS Humid2
FROM (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(data_string),
    SPLIT(data_string, ' ') AS parts
  FROM YourTable
);
```

To test with your real table  - use below part of script only --

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  published_at,
  parts[OFFSET(0)] AS Temp1,
  parts[OFFSET(1)] AS Humid1,
  parts[OFFSET(2)] AS Temp2,
  parts[OFFSET(3)] AS Humid2
FROM (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(data_string),
    SPLIT(data_string, ' ') AS parts
  FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
);
```

Comment: yes i have to wait for 3 more minutes  before the site allows me to accept :p

Comment: for some reason this works only for 2 rows then stops and i cannot figure out why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Evan - have you actually substitute `YourTable` with reference to your `real table`?! Elliott's answer is 100% correct but requires some little extra efforts from your side :o)  And don't forget to remove dummy data - this is just for you to make a quick test

Comment: you DO NOT need to change table name in WITH section!! just remove WITH section as it is for test only!

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, yes i substituted and the code is executable, but only producing a table of 2 or 1 rows depending on which data set is inputted, sorry if i was not clear, but i cannot figure out why it is not running for the rest of the rows

Comment: @Evan - i went ahead and added update to Elliott's answer - have you tried?

Comment: @Mikhail yes i tried your updated code, thank you, but i received this error- 'Error: Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "parts" at [8:3]'. Trying to figure out how to define parts now

Comment: the only change you supposed to do now is in FROM line - where instead of yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable you put real names and you have those embraced with back-ticks

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant this executes without error, but the resulting table has 2 rows only.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, edited post with up-to date query. thank you for your help

Comment: What can I say? Please read again above comments and my update/addition to answer!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, see edited post. I added both queries and their results

Comment: much closer (attempt 2) - so now  - provide fully qualified table name yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable enclosed with back-ticks as it is in my last example

Comment: Right. Just edited. Error: Array index 3 is out of bounds (overflow)

Comment: based on error  - looks like someof your rows have strings with less parts then you expect  - so use SAFE_OFFSET instead of OFFSET

Comment: THAT WORKS! Thank you

Comment: i am glad we did it  - and you re-accepted Elliott's answer again as it deserved it from the beginning!